# sc-win32-status code is -2147023901 in IIS7

Tags: iis-7

We are receiving the sc-win32-Status code as -2147023901 in case of Failed Requests. We didnt get much info when we googled on net.

Please throw some light as to whether the issue is related to any Network issue.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that error is really 995:

```
ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED
The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
```

Some libraries combine normal Windows error codes with some flags in the upper 16 bits of a DWORD value, which can hide the original number. If I see a negative number error code around -2100000000, I do this:

1. Convert to hex (with calc.exe or whatever) In this case decimal -2147023901 is hex 0x800703E3.
2. Take the lower 16 bits (0x00003E3)
3. Try to look that up. [For instance, on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231199.aspx).

Another handy trick that often works is to see if it can be decoded by certutil -error. From a command line:

```
C:\>certutil -error -2147023901
0x800703e3 (WIN32: 995) -- 2147943395 (-2147023901)
Error message text: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
CertUtil: -error command completed successfully.
```

Comment: Is this still applicable as of date?

Comment: thx it is still helpful